# In mpv, how to disable the playlist OSD when starting the next video in a playlist

Tags: linux, mpv

I've disabled osd:

```
osd-level=0
```

But when a new video in a playlist starts, in the upper left corner there appears the entire playlist. Using the option osd-scale, I can shrink it down, but how can I prevent it from automatically appearing at all?

It's okay to appear when clicking on the osc to see how the audio track is called, for example. But I'd like to disable the automatic appearance of the playlist text when the next video starts.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing [in the mpv documentation](https://mpv.io/manual/master/#options-osc) however if you look at mpv's `osc.lua` script there is the `playlist_osd` variable.

https://github.com/mpv-player/mpv/blob/master/player/lua/osc.lua#L53

You need to create `%APPDATA%\mpv\script-opts\osc.conf` and in it put:

```
playlist_osd=no
```

- Windows: `C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\mpv\script-opts\osc.conf`
- Linux: `~/.config/mpv/script-opts/osc.conf`

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but this doesn't work for me. Playlist is still in the upper left when switching to the next video in a playlist. Maybe my version of mpv is too old (0.33.0). I'm on LTS, but have mpv via a PPA.